# SQL: is it possible to limit a join condition based upon the row that was joined "before" the current row?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, mysql-8.0

I want to join this table onto itself, in order to connect the earliest borrow dates to the closest return dates that occurred within 15 days...can anyone figure out how to do so? I can't figure out a creative join condition...? recursion?

SELECT
trans_numb,
type,
date,
Borrow_occur,
return_occur
FROM borrow_data;

| trans_numb | type | date | Borrow_occur | return_occur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | BORROWED | 3/9/14 5:58 | 1 | NULL |
| 19 | BORROWED | 3/10/14 5:58 | 2 | NULL |
| 26 | BORROWED | 3/12/14 5:58 | 3 | NULL |
| 31 | RETURNED | 3/10/14 9:58 | NULL | 1 |
| 37 | RETURNED | 3/13/14 9:58 | NULL | 2 |
| 42 | BORROWED | 3/13/14 5:21 | 4 | NULL |
| 48 | BORROWED | 3/24/14 17:33 | 5 | NULL |
| 53 | RETURNED | 3/27/14 13:27 | NULL | 3 |
| 59 | RETURNED | 3/30/14 12:31 | NULL | 4 |
| 61 | BORROWED | 4/5/14 13:31 | 6 | NULL |
| 64 | RETURNED | 4/31/2014 7:31 | NULL | 5 |

Below is the desired output:

```
SELECT
r.type AS type_return,    
r.return_occur,    
r.date AS return_date,    
b.type AS type_borrow,    
b.borrow_occur,    
b.date AS borrow_date,    
Date_diff(r.date,b.date) AS date_diff   
FROM borrow_data r
LEFT JOIN borrow_data b ...
```

Notice how in row 3 borrow_occurance #3 is skipped b/c it occured > 15 days before the return...

and in row 5 its null b/c there are no purchases in the previous 15 days.

Thanks in advance

| (row_number) | type_return | return_occur | return_date | type_borrow | borrow_occur | borrow_date | date_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (1) | RETURNED | 1 | 3/10/14 9:58 | BORROWED | 1 | 3/9/14 5:58 | 1 |
| (2) | RETURNED | 2 | 3/13/14 9:58 | BORROWED | 2 | 3/10/14 5:58 | 3 |
| (3) | RETURNED | 3 | 3/27/14 13:27 | BORROWED | * 4 * | 3/13/14 5:21 | 14 |
| (4) | RETURNED | 4 | 3/30/14 12:31 | BORROWED | 5 | 3/24/14 17:33 | 6 |
| (5) | RETURNED | 5 | 4/31/2014 7:31 | NULL | * NULL * | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Please provide the structure of both tables.

Comment: Should borrow_occur and return_occur always match? In your sample result set on row 3 and 4, the occurs don't match.

Comment: @gfreeman No, they should not, that is the point and the difficulty here I am having

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this query (it is for PostgreSQL but I hope you get the idea):

```
SELECT *, EXTRACT(DAY FROM t1.date-t2.date) AS date_diff FROM test AS t1
LEFT JOIN test AS t2 ON t2.borrow_occur = t1.return_occur AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM t1.date-t2.date) <= 15
WHERE t1.type='RETURNED'
ORDER BY t1.return_occur
```

This is the table data I am using:

[image: table data]

Which produces the output:

[image: The output]

It only JOINs if there is a BORROWED Entry in the last 15 Days. I am not checking for minutes etc only for days. You have to fine tune it as you like. Let me know if I misunderstood any requirements.